# How to setup a Docker MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, docker

My provider has "extended" my Plesk with MariaDB. Unfortunately, some things don't work anymore, so I'm looking for a way to install MySQL. That is why I'm looking for a way to install MySQL via Docker.

```
docker run -p 33060:3306 --name mysql-docker-eMYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXXX -d mysql
```

The MySQL server also seems to work - but only locally. But I can't connect from outside. I also tried to disable the firewall, temporarily. It wont work..

Can someone please help me to correctly install a MySQL server with Docker and how I can connect to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Check your docker command carefully, you don't have space before and after  **-e**. The command must be

```
run -p 33060:3306 --name mysql-docker -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXXX -d mysql
```

I checked it worked for me

[image]

Comment: Thx for your response. Well, it works when I access the DB on the host. But whenever I try to get access to the DB via an SSH tunnel it fails

Comment: In your host mysql's my.cnf set the bind address to 0.0.0.0 so that mysql listens on all network interfaces ,  bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Comment: fond the mistakes(s). First of all the `docker.lock` had not the correct permissions and then the user in the database missed in some permissions too. Now it works. Thx a lot!